# How to call one function of a running process a.js from another running process b.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs project there I have a http server bootstrap file let's call it a.js and another is MQTT broker let's call it b.js

So http server is in express and MQTT broker is in aedes if that helps. For some workflow I need to call a function that is in http server's codebase FROM mqtt broker's codebase, if that is possible.
I already know that I can rather create an API in http server and call that url from b.js using some http lib. like axios but that is not what I find elegant is there some other way to cross-communicate across a.js and b.js when they are running as a separate process

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want one nodejs instance to make a remote procedure call (RPC) to another nodejs instance and retrieve results.  Web services are, as you know, a  canonical, auditable, documentable, loggable, testable way to do that.  If you want to use some other RPC scheme, you'll have to implement it. But I suspect you'll end up with a wrapper around a web service. There  are quite a few frameworks layered on node - express to help you create web services efficiently.   https://expressjs.com/en/resources/frameworks.html  (Don't reinvent the flat tire!)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want one function that is used by a.js and b.js running in the same environment then you're best to share that specific call in another file c.js and bring it in like a library or other api

a.js

```
const customFunction = require('c.js');
// Some express code
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Server Specific Logic
  customFunction(...);
});
```

b.js

```
const customFunction = require('c.js');
// Other App Code
customFunction(...);
```

c.js

```
module.exports = function() { 
  // Shared function here brought in when other files require('c.js')
}
```